# retrieve files created within a time range in a local folder

Tags: c#, windows

Need to retrieve files created within a time range (in granular of minute level)  in a local folder (files are flat in the folder, no sub-directories). Using Windows OS and want to find if any C# code to refer to? My current solution is native, which scan folder for all files and filter by timestamp. It works but if there is a more neat Windows API which could filter file by timestamp, it should be more reliable than my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FileSystemWatcher` Which have an event that raises when a file is created:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher() {
                Path = "c:\\",
                IncludeSubdirectories = true,
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName,
                Filter = "*.*"
            };
 watcher.Created += (s, e) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.FullPath);
            };
```

[FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks Ashkan, vote up. Could this API used in Windows Store App as well?

Comment: Another question is, if I only need to monitor file creation event, what events  should I monitor? It seems a very long document. :)

Comment: Thanks Ashkan, very very cool. Do you know if it works for Windows Store app?

Comment: Nice, thanks Ashkan. Will do some experiment and if no issues, will mark it as answered. :)

Comment: Ashkan, thanks for all the help, mark your reply as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

directory.GetFiles().Where(x => x.CreationTime.Date > from.Date && x.CreationTime.Date <= to.date)

where to and from are the ranges.

Comment: Thanks venkat, vote up. Is it C#? :)

And could this solution used in Windows Store App as well?

Comment: it is c#. i'm not sure about store app, but  it should work.